# Complicated SQL query: Matching language skills between projects and users

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my PostgreSQL database, I'm trying to write a query that will match **Consultants** with **Projects** based on their **Language skills**.

Let me give you an example:

We have a project that is looking for **Consultants** in **Berlin** city that have a German on **at least 3 level**. Our query as a result should match which consultant match specific requirement.

I have the following query that matches if **Consultant city** is equal to **Project city**:

```
SELECT
    consultant_profiles.id,
    CASE WHEN (consultant_profiles.city = projects.city)
        THEN 0.5
        ELSE 0 END AS city_matching

FROM
    consultant_profiles

LEFT OUTER JOIN
    projects ON projects.id = 1;
```

and it returns following results:

```
id  city_matching
1   0.5
2   0
```

Now I would like to update this query to have information if the language skils are matching

```
id  city_matching language_skills_matching
1   0.5           1      
1   0             0
```

Is there a way to achieve those results somehow in PostgreSQL?

Here is how my schema looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE public.consultant_profiles (
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  name character varying,
  city character varying
);

CREATE TABLE public.projects (
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  name character varying,
  city character varying
);

CREATE TABLE public.language_skills (
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  language character varying,
  level integer,
  owner_type character varying,
  owner_id integer
);

INSERT INTO consultant_profiles (id, name, city) VALUES (1, 'Consultant with native German and English', 'Berlin');
INSERT INTO consultant_profiles (id, name, city) VALUES (1, 'Consultant with native French', 'Warsaw');

INSERT INTO projects (id, name, city) VALUES (1, 'Projects that requires at least German level 3',  'Berlin');
INSERT INTO projects (id, name, city) VALUES (2, 'Projects that requires at least English level 3', 'Berlin');

INSERT INTO language_skills (id, language, level, owner_id, owner_type) VALUES (1, 'German',  4, 1, 'ConsultantProfile');
INSERT INTO language_skills (id, language, level, owner_id, owner_type) VALUES (2, 'English', 4, 1, 'ConsultantProfile');

INSERT INTO language_skills (id, language, level, owner_id, owner_type) VALUES (4, 'German',  3, 1, 'Project');
INSERT INTO language_skills (id, language, level, owner_id, owner_type) VALUES (5, 'English', 3, 2, 'Project');
```

Here is a DB Fiddle link:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gSRxQ9o3rgVTnbkPezxDKn/1

Comment: Your sample data *seems* to only have one language skill per project, if I'm reading it right, but will that always be the case? If this is a matter of matching multiple skills between consultants and projects, it sounds like what you're looking for is a variation of *relational division*.

Comment: Project can have multiple language skills required. I did that because I tried to simplify the example a little bit.

Comment: @MateuszUrbański: you probably want to show how multiple skills should be handled - otherwise the answer you will receive will not be able to address this use case. Also, although it is great to provide a fiddle (few questions do!),  it would be great to put the sample data and desired results directly in the question as well (the fiddle link will be gone in some time, while the SO question will still be there).

Comment: It looks like you are asking "For all Consultants, what Projects are in their cities" as opposed to "For all Projects, what Consultants are in their cities", is that correct? It also looks like you only want to report on project 1, is that also correct?

Comment: Yes the results are only for one project so the project_id will be hardcoded in the query always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure how you wanted multiple language requirements handled, but the below solution will register the consultant as a language match if he has any language proficiency sufficient to satisfy any project language requirement

EDIT: You asked if I could modify it to tell if ALL language requirements were met instead of ANY, the below query adds a field for ALL. To make it a bit easier to read and debug I added a CTE that gathers the language requirements for the project, but that step could have been combined with another, I just think it's a bit clearer this way.

NOTE: I added a new project and a new consultant to test the combinations of multiple languages, so the data is larger here.

```
DECLARE @ProjID int = 3;
--START of sample data
with cteConsult as (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES (1, 'Abe(Germ,Eng)', 'Berlin')
        , (2, 'Ben(Fr)', 'Warsaw')
        , (3, 'Carl(Eng)', 'Berlin')
    ) as consult(con_id, con_name, con_city)
), cteProj as (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES (1, 'Proj 1(G3)', 'Berlin')
        , (2, 'Proj 2 (E3)', 'Berlin')
        , (3, 'Proj 3 (E3G3)', 'Berlin')
    ) as proj(proj_id, proj_name, proj_city)
), cteLang as (
SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES (1, 'German', 4, 1, 'cons')
        , (2, 'English', 4, 1, 'cons')
        , (4, 'German', 3, 1, 'proj')
        , (5, 'English', 3, 2, 'proj')
        , (6, 'English', 3, 3, 'cons')
        --, (7, 'German', 3, 3, 'cons')
        , (8, 'English', 3, 3, 'proj')
        , (9, 'German', 3, 3, 'proj')
    ) as lang(lang_req_id, lang_name, prof_level, owner_id, owner_type)
)--END sample data, begin actual solution
, cteReq as ( --Collect the laguage requirements into a cte
    SELECT * 
    FROM cteLang as LP 
    WHERE LP.owner_type = 'proj' AND LP.owner_id = @ProjID
)--select * from cteReq as R
SELECT C.con_name, P.proj_id, p.proj_name
    , CASE WHEN (C.con_city = P.proj_city )
        THEN 0.5
        ELSE 0 END AS city_matching --Up to here is your existing query
    , CASE WHEN EXISTS ( --Add this field - JOIN the LANGUAGE table to itself on LANGUAGE
                SELECT * --and see if it has any rows where the CONS proficiency is >= the PROJ proficiency
                FROM cteLang as LC INNER JOIN cteLang as LP on LC.lang_name = LP.lang_name
                WHERE LC.owner_type = 'cons' AND LC.owner_id = C.con_id
                    AND LP.owner_type = 'proj' AND LP.owner_id = P.proj_id 
                    AND LC.prof_level >= LP.prof_level 
            )
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as any_language_matched
    , CASE WHEN EXISTS ( --if there exists a requirement where there 
                SELECT * --does not exist a corresponding proficiency
                FROM cteReq as R --for the consultant we are considering
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cteLang as LC 
                    WHERE LC.lang_name = R.lang_name
                        AND LC.prof_level >= R.prof_level 
                        AND LC.owner_type='cons' AND LC.owner_id = c.con_id)
            ) --then mark the language requirement as unfulfilled
            THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as all_language_matched
FROM cteConsult as C 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cteProj as P on P.proj_id = @ProjID
```

| con_name | proj_id | proj_name | city_matching | any_language_matched | all_language_matched |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abe(Germ,Eng) | 3 | Proj 3 (E3G3) | 0.5 | 1 | 1 |
| Ben(Fr) | 3 | Proj 3 (E3G3) | 0.0 | 0 | 0 |
| Carl(Eng) | 3 | Proj 3 (E3G3) | 0.5 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Thank you very much Robert for your answer. Do you think it is possible to match multiple language requirements in your solution? For example: Project requires Consultant that have German 4 level and English 4 level and we only return 1 if all of those language skills are matched.

Comment: Yes @MateuszUrbański, see the edited solution for a "ALL matched" as well as "ANY matched"